# Best way to avoid duplicates in table?

Tags: t-sql

I've been given a task that requires writing a script to mass change items in a table(ProductArea):

```
ProductID int
SalesareaID int
```

One ProductID can only exist once in each SalesareaID so there can't be any duplicates in this table. But one ProductID can be sold in multiple SalesareaID.
So an example would look something like:

```
ProductID SalesareaID
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         2
3         1
```

Now, some areas have merged. So, if I try to run a straight-forward UPDATE to fix this like:

```
UPDATE ProductArea SET SalesareaID = 4 where SalesareaID IN (2, 3)
```

it will find (1, 2) and change that to (1, 4). Then it will find (1, 3) and try to change that to (1, 4). But that already exist so it will crash with a "Cannot insert duplicate key..."-error.

Is there a best/recommended way to tell my UPDATE to only update if the resulting (ProductID, SalesareaID) doesn't already exist?

Comment: Actually, the best and easiest way is to let the database raise that error an handle it.

Comment: I think you need to properly write your UPDATE statement so that it doesn't produce duplicates. Perhaps... write an insert to a new table that changes everything (that isn't uniquely keyed) then `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <temp table>;` into your final table. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work
It uses a window function

```
declare @T table (prodID int, salesID int, primary key (prodID, salesID));
insert into @T values 
       (1, 1)
     , (1, 2)
     , (1, 3)
     , (2, 2)
     , (3, 1);
with cte as 
( select t.* 
       , row_number() over (partition by t.prodID order by t.salesID) as rn
  from @T t 
  where t.salesID in (2, 3) 
)
delete cte where rn > 1;
update @T set salesID = 4 where salesID in (2, 3);
select * from @T;
```

Comment: What if you set the new salesID value to 1? or -4? You'ld have to change your query...

Comment: @ZoharPeled No kidding

Comment: Forget about it, lack of sleep. I was thinking about the delete statement that might not work as expected. I see my mistake now. I do think, however, that there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new merged region from existing regions then I think the easiest thing to do would be to treat the merge as two separate operations.

First you insert entries for the new area based on the existing areas.

```
INSERT INTO ProductArea (ProductID, SalesareaID)
SELECT DISTINCT ProductID, 4 FROM ProductArea
WHERE SalesareaID IN (2, 3)
```

Then you remove the entries for the existing areas.

```
DELETE FROM ProductArea WHERE SalesareaID IN (2, 3)
```

The SalesareaID of 4 would need to be replaced by the id of the new Salesarea. The 2 and 3 would also need to be replaced by the ids of the areas you are merging to create the new Salesarea.

Comment: Fails if ProductID = 4 exists

Comment: @paparazzo how so?

Comment: Uh, PK violation.  Why don't you test.

Comment: @paparazzo The ProductID comes from the other two sales areas so it shouldn't matter what value it has. If you meant it fails when SalesareaID = 4 then yes you would be correct. I'm assuming that there's some mechanism for coming up with the id of the new merged area.

Comment: But it is not necessarily a new merged area.  This is what the OP is asking for help with.

Comment: From the question I got the impression that they were merging 2 and 3 to create 4. If they are merging 2, 3, and 4 then yes this won't work. I will update my answer to make this clear.